# Executing Sed Command

Tags: linux, sed

When I run the command

```
sed -e "s/$1/@root@The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy/" -i gen_certs.sh
```

I Get the following error. I am trying to replace the text $1 with the other below in the same file, not creating a new one just modifying the current one.

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression
```

Any ideas what could be causing the error and how to fix it?

OS: Ubuntu 10.10 32 bit

Comment: `-i` specifies the suffix for in-place-editing.

Comment: try escaping the dollar sign: \$1

Answer (score 3):

`$1` will expand to a null-string(`''`) if it's in double-qouted string.
You can use single quote to keep the literal value of`$1`:

```
sed -e 's/$1/@root@The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy/' -i gen_certs.sh
```

Comment: Overall this worked, thanks for that. Though it replaces it with @root@The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy , I thought @ was supposed to be a replacement for the /

Comment: @awmusic12635, no, `@` won't magically change into `/`. you can use different delimiters for the `s///` command though: `sed -e 's!$1!/root/The...!' -i gen_certs.sh`

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the pattern: `sed -e "s/\$1/@root@The-Three-Little-Pigs-Siri-Proxy/" -i gen_certs.sh`, since `$1` denotes a back reference in sed (presuming you want to replace the string `$1` in your input, right?)

Comment: Yes I want to replace the string $1 since I'm not using it as a variable

Comment: I think you may be confusing perl with sed. `\1` denotes a back reference in sed. If it were a back reference it would need to be defined by a grouping e.g. `\(.\)` beforehand. As the sed commands are double quoted the shell interprets `$1` and returns nothing and hence sed sees `//` an empty regexp. Unless there is a previous regexp this will fail.

Comment: @potong Right you are! Of course, it was a shell expansion. Got confused, sorry.